# Changing motor RPM

Tags: circuit-analysis, motor, circuit-design, motor-controller

I bought a motor which has these characteristics:
RPM: 2800
HP: 3
Voltage: 240V 50Hz AC

For the application I will be using this motor, I need to keep the existing RPM of the motor (2800) and in some cases the motor needs to reduce the RPM to 1400. Is this possible? I want to make a switch to switch either between 2800 RPM or 1400 RPM. Can you please guide me on how I can make this possible? I don't want to vary the speed of the motor by changing the pulleys.

Thank you very much

Comment: What are the manufacturer and model of the motor? Please add that information to the question.

Comment: What is the basic type of motor? If you don't know, please take a clear picture of the name plate on the motor that has all the information. Take a second picture of the whole motor so we can see it.

Comment: Best speed control uses a 3ph motor with VFD, poor load regulated speed occurs with simple SCR controllers but cheap https://www.amazon.ca/uniquegoods-Electronic-Regulator-Controller-Thermoregulation/dp/B07W12ZLF7/ref=sr_1_20?dchild=1&keywords=single+phase+motor+speed+control&qid=1612638230&s=hi&sr=1-20

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a VFD (Variable-Frequency Drive) it should do the job nicely for your application. A VFD can be gotten in the $100 or less depending on source. Another possibility is a inverter drive is a type of motor drive used in electro-mechanical drive systems to control AC motor speed and torque by varying motor input frequency and voltage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any VFDs in mind I can use? Keep in mind that these will be in dusty conditions (cutting stone and bricks)

Comment: @EmanuelCassar, seeking product recommendations is off-topic on this site and will get your question closed. Note that you didn't post the information requested in the comments under your question so we don't know what type of motor you have and so a VFD may not be suitable. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a 3-phase motor, you can buy a variable frequency drive (VFD), an electronic motor control product. I doubt that is a 3-phase motor because 2800 RPM is a bit low to be a standard speed. For good 3-phase, a standard speed would be about 2850 to 2870 RPM.

You could also get a new motor. Something close to 1400 RPM, say 1450 to 1470 RPM would be a standard speed for a 50 H, 3-phase motor. A standard speed for a single-phase motor would be closer to 1400 RPM.

You might be able to find a VFD for a single-phase motor, but it would be rather expensive and difficult to find. Whether the VFD would good performance or even work at all would depend on the specific type of single-phase motor and the load characteristics.

If 3-phase power is available, it would be best to buy a 3-phase, 1400 RPM motor. If only single-phase power is available, then buy a single-phase 1400 RPM motor. If you don't need variable speed, there is little or no possible advantage in using a VFD to change the frequency unless you have a motor that would be very difficult to replace. There are some disadvantages.

Keep in mind that power is torque multiplied by speed. A 3 Hp, 1400-RPM motor will have twice as much torque as a 3-Hp, 2800-RPM motor. If you are going to buy both a motor and a VFD, it is best to carefully consider what is required for each, consider what is required for them to work together then buy both. In this case, it seems highly likely that the best solution is to buy a suitable motor that can do the job without a VFD. If you have access to a local seller that you trust to provide good advice and support, buy from that seller. If you decide that you need both a VFD and a motor, buy both from the same trusted seller.

Comment: It is a single phase motor

Comment: See paragraph added to my answer. It is best to revise the question to add information rather than put additional information in comments. You have added information in comments to three answers. All of that should be in the question.

Comment: See paragraph added about buying.

Comment: @EmanuelCassar, "*It is a single phase motor.*" That information is missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answer, you need a VFD.  Here's why.

I am making a guess, based on the fact that it's a 3HP motor that runs on AC and rotates at a bit less than a synchronous speed*, that it's an induction motor.

Induction motors "want" to run at some constant slip speed (200RPM in your case) below synchronous speed.  So if you want to run the thing at 1400RPM, you'd need to drive it at about 32Hz.  In order to do this in a sane, economical, and controlled manner, you want to use a variable frequency drive (VFD).

Note that you need to take care: motors that are designed to just run at line frequency sometimes don't "like" running off of VFDs.  I haven't personally done this so I can't tell you all the pitfalls, but the two that I know of are, first, lower speed means lower airflow, which means more heating, and second, VFDs often 'chop' their outputs; this chopping causes eddy currents in the motor armature, which again causes more heating.

If you're building a product that's going to be duplicated hundreds of times, just specify a motor rated for VFD use.  If you're doing a one-off it's up to you, but what I'd do is get a VFD, use it, and in the first hundred hours or so of operation I'd check to make sure the motor's not overheating.  I might run it for extended periods at 1400 RPM just to check.  Then I'd continue to check it periodically after that (because dirty motors shed heat less efficiently).  If all seemed well, I'd call it good.

* The synchronous speed of an AC motor is the AC line frequency expressed as cycles per minute.  So 50Hz = 50 cycles per second = 3000 cycles per minute.  Your motor turns at 2800 revolutions (cycles) per minute, or about 93% of the synchronous speed -- it's almost certainly an induction motor.

Comment: Thanks for the information, really helpful. Do you have any idea of VFDs I can use? I can establish the VFD first and then buy the motor according to the VFD

Comment: It seems be a single-phase motor based on information buried in the comments under Charles' answer.